# Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

Everything works fine on dev (npm run dev) but after build I have this error:

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined.

Without BlotFormatter module it also works fine.
It is laravel + vue + inertia + vite + VueQuill

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <QuillEditor theme="snow" :modules="modules"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
    import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter'
    import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';

    export default  {
        components: {
            QuillEditor
        },
        setup: () => {
            const modules = {
                name: 'blotFormatter',  
                module: BlotFormatter, 
                options: {/* options */}
            }
        return { modules }
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your BlotFormatter to:

```
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter/dist/BlotFormatter'
```

Detail issue in: https://github.com/Fandom-OSS/quill-blot-formatter/issues/39